# Атрибут срабатывающий при нажатии

Tags: bootstrap

Есть выпадающее меню, когда мы наводим мышкой на элемент срабатывает атрибут  :hover, когда кликаем по элементу выпадающего списка срабатывает :focus.
НО в :focus я прописываю border: none, но всё равно при клике как на кнопку выпадающего меню так и на один из пунктов списка я вижу синюю рамку:

[image]

Я уже и прописал в стилях везде где только можно border:none;

```
.dropdown-menu li a:focus{
background: transparent ;
color: red ;
}
.dropdown-menu li :focus{
background: transparent ;
color: red ;
border: none;
}
.dropdown-menu :focus{
background: transparent ;
color: red ;
border: none;
}
```

Цвет при нажатии меняется на красный, а граница не пропадает :D

Comment: Покажите пример в jsfiddle, пожалуйста

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15267/

Comment: Меню не отображается.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/v4Ubve6.png вроде всё отображается...

Comment: На маленьком  экране пропадает )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта штука называется `outline`. Просто добавьте к стилям следующую строку

```
outline:0;
```